# Access Android system color palette from JavaScript in browser

Tags: material-design

I'm experimenting with [material components for web](https://github.com/material-components/material-web) and I want it to use my android phone's system color palette. Support for material you in the web library is planned, but I can use css variables to theme my material components, so is there a way I can get the system palette and manually apply it?